# Why doesn't BOOST_HOF_LIFT work on MSVC, with error C2892?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, c++17, language-lawyer

Why does the following fail to compile on MSVC?

```
#include <boost/hof/lift.hpp>
int foo(int);
int foo(double);
inline auto bar = BOOST_HOF_LIFT(foo);
int main() {
    bar(1);
    bar(1.1);
}
```

whereas this is fine?

```cpp
#include <boost/hof/lift.hpp>
int foo(int);
int foo(double);
BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS(Baz, foo);
inline auto baz = Baz{};
int main() {
    baz(1);
    baz(1.1);
}
```

Clang and GCC are fine with either. ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5371nd7Kv))

I've looked into the definition of `BOOST_HOF_LIFT` and `BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS`, but haven't managed to understand (it's a macro hell) why the compilers behave differently.

But the error on MSVC,

```
<source>(4): error C2892: a template cannot be a member of a local class
```

seems pretty clearly to hint to the fact that `BOOST_HOF_LIFT` defines a class (via `BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS`) locally to a lambda body, and then returns an object of that class:

```cpp
#define BOOST_HOF_LIFT(...) (BOOST_HOF_STATIC_LAMBDA { BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS(fit_local_lift_t, __VA_ARGS__); return fit_local_lift_t(); }())
```

But this is precisely under

```cpp
#if defined (_MSC_VER)
```

So I'd expect to work for that platform.

On the other hand, if the error message refers to something like

```cpp
    auto f = ([]{
        struct Foo {
            template<class T>
            constexpr auto operator()(T&& x) const {
                return x;
            }
        };
        return Foo{};
    })();
```

than that's wrong for all 3 compilers, so it must mean something (slightly?) different.

Comment: There are others that also believe it should be allowed [Allow Templates in Local Classes](https://wg21.link/p1988)

Answer (score 1):

Local classes, except for closure types (i.e. lambdas), cannot have member templates. See [[temp.mem]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp#mem-2.sentence-1).

So MSVC's behavior in rejecting `BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS` in the lambda is valid, as is the behavior of all compilers in your last example. However, `BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS` at global scope is well-formed, because it won't be a local class.

However, `BOOST_HOF_LIFT` only expands to `BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS` on MSVC. There are individual implementations for each compiler implemented via `#ifdef`s on compiler-identifying macros, which is why `BOOST_HOF_LIFT` works on GCC and Clang.

If the MSVC version isn't working, it should probably be modified to be compatible with MSVC. Apparently older versions of MSVC did permit the local class member template. There is already an open github issue [here](https://github.com/boostorg/hof/issues/220).

A proposal to permit local classes to have member templates was made in [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/774), but it hasn't seen any progress since 2021.