# How do I answer the question of whether a standard library function is an "addressable function"?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, memory-address

I've recently come across [*Can I take the address of a function defined in standard library?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library) and was shocked by the fact that the answer is fundamentally [*No*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55687045/5825294). I surely have written `&std::someTemplClass<SomeConcreteType>::someMember` in a few places at least, so I should review all of them, but how do I go about it?

From [the relevant piece of the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#6),

> […] Unless `F` is designated an *addressable function*, the behavior of a C++ program is unspecified […]

it feels like I have to search the standard for all the `std::stuff` to which I've applied `&` and look for the words *"addressable function"*.

But how can I be sure I've looked at the correct page for a given `std::stuff`?

[The linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55687045/5825294) surely makes two examples, but I still have some doubts.

For instance:

> Moreover, the behavior of a C++ program is unspecified (possibly ill-formed) if it attempts to form a reference to `F` or if it attempts to form a pointer-to-member designating either a standard library non-static member function ([member.functions]) or an instantiation of a standard library member function template.

Does this mean that *a standard library non-static member function* and *an instantiation of a standard library member function template* are never an *addressable function*?

If that's the case, am I correct to understand that any occurrence of `&std::someTemplClass<SomeConcreteType>::someNonStaticMemberFunc` or even just `&std::someClass::someMemberFunc` passed to a higher order function, such as in these cases,

```
doStuff(someRange | ranges::views::filter(&std::optional<int>::has_value));
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(),
               w.begin(),
               boost::bind( &std::string::c_str, boost::placeholders::_1 ) );
```

is wrong?

And what about it being in unevaluated context, e.g. `decltype(&std::someTemplClass<SomeConcreteType>::someNonStaticMember)`?

---

Please, don't tell me the answer is *"you should read the standard **end-to-end**"* :(

Answer (score 4):

There is a, hopefully complete and maintained, list of these addressable functions at

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction

The addressable functions are only such functions that are designed for the use case to be passed to other functions (usually as by-reference). These are (currently) all IO streams-related. So the list is pretty small.

Yes, there are no addressable member functions of standard library templates or addressable specializations of function templates.

All the examples you give are not addressable and therefore have unspecified behavior. It is not undefined behavior, so it isn't that bad. The risk is that it may not compile on a different compiler or (less likely) that it may choose the wrong overload/specialization of the function.

Whether the context is evaluated or not doesn't matter. This is a question of overload resolution to give the standard library writer leeway to implement functions with different overloads/templates than specified in the standard. Generally it is only guaranteed that standard library functions behave according to their specification in direct calls.

When passing standard library functions as higher order functions the way you are doing it, you should pass them indirected through a lambda, as e.g. implemented by [`BOOST_HOF_LIFT`](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/lift.html). Unfortunately there is currently no nicer syntax for that in the language.

Also consider that the same problem may apply to other libraries. If the library writer was to guarantee that functions are addressable in the sense of "addressable function" in the standard, then that will strongly restrict them when making changes to the library. They would need to commit to not change the overload set of library functions or evaluate such changes very carefully.

Comment: ([I know you know I'm aware of `BOOST_HOF_LIFT` :P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77666976/why-doesnt-boost-hof-lift-work-on-msvc-with-error-c2892))

Comment: If a library is updated and it adds overloads to, say, `std::optional<T>::has_value`, any usage of `&std::optional<sometype>::has_value` will fail to compile, so I see that and solve by wrapping a lambda around it. If a function with default args change its default args, that will affect also the wrapped-in-lambda approach. So can such an unspecified behavior have an effect and pass unnoticed (unnoticed = you discover some weird behavior of your program, or tests fail in a weird way...)?

Comment: @Enlico The lambda needs to do a direct call: `[](const std::optional &x){return x.has_value();}`. I'm not sure if `BOOST_HOF_LIFT` can do this, but you can write your own macro.

Comment: @Enlico I don't think it is likely to happen, but you can come up with all kinds of special cases. I am not sure about `has_value` specifically. But even the fact that adding an overload may make overload resolution ambiguous implies that it can cause candidate functions to be dropped in overload resolution of the function that you are passing the pointer to. That can in theory arbitrarily affect behavior.

Comment: @Enlico More likely are maybe scenarios where you take a pointer to a specialization `template<typename T> f(T);` as `&f<int>`, but then a non-template overload for `int` is added that will be ignored because it doesn't match `<int>`. However, in that case directly calling as `f<int>(...)` would also be affected. In some cases the standard library also doesn't guarantee calling with explicit template arguments for that reason.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, that is a comment to "will affect also the wrapped-in-lambda approach"?

Comment: @Enlico Yes. You just need to do the wrapping correctly.

Comment: @Enlico Actually the default argument case is a good example. If you have `void f(int, int=0);` and `void f(long);` and you pass `g(f)` to a function `template<typename T> void g(void(*)(T));`, then it will select and use the second `f` overload even for `int` arguments, which in direct calling would be impossible and unintended by the library author. The lambda approach avoids this issue.

Comment: @user17732522, thinking about your last comment again, I'm not convinced. [I see what the problem with that code is](https://godbolt.org/z/zaevxzn1G), but the code doesn't use `&` to take the address of anything in the first place (the conversion to function pointer is happening via decay); if I had written `g(&f)`, then that wouldn't even have compiled. Or, it would have stopped compile as soon as `void f(int, int=0)` was introduced beside the pre-existing `g` and `void f(long)` (the other way around, `f(int, int=0)` pre-dating `f(long)` was not possible, because `g` wouldn't have compiled).

Answer (score 3):

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Designated_addressable_functions) has a list of addressable functions, and it contains only iostream manipulators.

I've checked the standard draft, and the only places where the word "addressable" appears (outside of its definition) are all [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/input.output) (so indeed only manipulators).

So yes, your examples are illegal.

Including in unevaluated context. The point of this rule is to be able to quietly add overloads and change their signatures, as long as the call syntax looks normal. If the function you pass to `decltype(&foo)` ends up overloaded, you'll get a compilation error.